# How can I set a variable on a function component with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to nest MenuItem as variable on the Select component from Material UI so I can expose a single component for building dropdown inputs:

```
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select'
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';

Select.Item = MenuItem

export default Select
```

Doing this throws the following Typescript error:

```
TS2339: Property 'Item' does not exist on type '(props: SelectProps) => Element'.
```

Is doing this possible with TypeScript? I can't seem to think of how to alter the type definition of an existing component in order to set a variable on it.

Comment: This feels like a XY problem: what is the reason behind adding a `MenuItem` to `Select`, when `Select` is not an instance but a class?

Comment: It may seem daft. I'm using react-native-web, and I'd like a single interface for all UI components, even those where I need to split the web and native code. I'm using react-native-picker for the native side, which exposes the menu item as `Picker.Item`. So I'd like to use the same interface for the Material UI component as well.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think this will work due to what @Terry was saying above (`Select` is not an instance but a class).  That is, your problem is not solely with typing, but even with just javascript will not do what you think.  To solve your issue, you could create a new component that very thinly wraps Select, but also includes an Item property.

Answer (score 0):

I got this messed up ts code. I don't think it will work but just to give you an idea, a new approach.

```
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select'
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';

interface IMenuItem extends Select = {
   Item: MenuItem;
}

_Select<IMenuItem> = Select;

_Select.Item = MenuItem;

export default _Select
```

Comment: I had tried it using `//@ts-ignore`, tried it with your suggestion just now and still no go

Comment: I changed my code, please check it one more time. I don't think it will work. It may give you a new idea.

Comment: Been playing around with your suggestion, can't seem to import both the component and the types properly. I found something promising, but keep getting `JSX element type 'Select' does not have any construct or call signatures.` I appreciate your help, I think I'm gonna take the long way around with this one and try another approach.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has a similar issue, here's what I ended up doing:

As Kevin Wang pointed out, you can't set a variable on the definition of a functional component. Instead I created a stateful class component and set a static member.

```
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select'
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';

class SelectComponent extends React.Component<SelectProps> {
    static Item = MenuItem

    render() {
        return (
            <Select>{ this.props.children }</Select>
        )
    }
}

export default SelectComponent
```

I think it's kinda funny that after adopting hooks and stateless functional components so completely, I didn't consider that a class component could be a solution anymore.